# (background) image not reaching width of screen

Tags: flutter

I have changed from using BoxDecoration:

```
     decoration: new BoxDecoration(
       shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
       image: new DecorationImage(
         fit: BoxFit.fill,
         image: new NetworkImage(urlString),
       ),
     ),
    );
```

To FadeImage:

```
return FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
      placeholder: kTransparentImage,
      image: urlString,
    );
```

Where URL string is  `https://source.unsplash.com/collection/3302326/414x896/?sig=42` The values of width=414 and height of 896 come from:

```
var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toInt();
var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toInt();
```

I can't use BoxDecoration with FadeInImage, so I lose BoxFit.fill.  I thought if I got the screen's width and height, I would have an image that would cover the screen.  What I got was a width that was about 105 pixels less in width than needed to cover the width of the screen.  I then tried SizedBox.extended... but still could not get the FadeInImage to span the width of the screen.

What am i missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply - `FadeInImage` widget does the work.

```
FadeInImage(
              placeholder: kTransparentImage,
              image: NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/414/896/any'),  // replace this with urlString in your code.
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
```

Output:

[image]

**UPDATE:** to make sure widget take whole screen area.

```
FadeInImage(
        height: double.infinity,  //add this
        width: double.infinity,   //add this
        placeholder: kTransparentImage,
        image: NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any'),  // replace this with urlString in your code.
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you.  I still have the challenge.  I think it has to do with the actual width and height of the image I'm getting from unsplash.  In order to reach the entire width, I have to specify the width is about width + heigh ~/8 -> i.e.: make the width wider than the MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toInt(); says it is.

Comment: just make sure you widget cover screen, than `fit: BoxFit.cover` can stretch image to cover whole screen - so image height/width wont matter that much. @user1255603

Comment: ii took out the width and height of the image, but fit: BoxFit.cover still does not stretch the width of the screen.

Comment: @user1255603 - you got the wrong idea- i mean widget needs to take whole space - then image height/width don't matter. updated the answer. you can check